# Update form and table on input update on real time with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following form and table:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="VA" />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="VB" />
    <p class="ratio">{{VA / VB}}</p>
  </form>

  <table>
    <caption>Classification</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Medium</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>High</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

I would like to display the ratio on p tag when VA and VB are both different from null and to change the class of TR to highlight according to the rule:

```
ratio < 0.4 => Low
0.4 <= ratio <= 0.8 => Medium
ratio > 0.8 => High
```

How can I do this? And do I need a controller?
Can't this be made directly on HTML?

Comment: you can use ng-class. Can you provide a fidle?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="VA" />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="VB" />
    <p ng-show="!!(!!VA && !!VB)" class="ratio">{{VA / VB}}</p>
  </form>

  <table>
    <caption>Classification</caption>
    <tr ng-class="{ratio<0.4:'low', ratio=<0.8 && ratio>=0.4:'medium', ration>0.8:'high'}">
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Medium</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>High</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you think there is any advantage on using a controller such type of calculators?

Comment: @Miguel In my implementations I am trying to work only with directives (Angular 2.0 and web-components approach) and only if the calculation is somehow complex to have a controller. But I believe that your ratio should be calculated inside your directive, like `$scope.ratio = VA/VB` . It is easier for debugging. And you should use one-way binding if the ratio doesnt change during a session e.g. `{{::ratio}}`